# How do I install Skype or Viber on Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, voip

How do I install Skype or Viber on Ubuntu Touch?

My platform: Google Nexus 4, Ubuntu Touch stable

Comment: Skype and Viber are proprietary applications. Before they can be installed, you'll need to convince the vendors to provide them for Ubuntu touch.

Comment: If you are wanting to make Video calls - not specifically Skype - then it looks like you'll be able to use Google Hangouts when OTA-11 comes out. Here's a link that Jens Grivolla found (http://plus.google.com/+OliverGrawert/posts/aZi13q1bcWw) in answer to a question about Hangouts not working at the moment. The question is here: (http://askubuntu.com/questions/759832/ubuntu-touch-google-hangouts-on-bq-m10)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, contact the Skype or Viber vendors (Microsoft, in the case of Skype) and ask them if they provide packages for Ubuntu on phones.

Comment: I contacted Viber for Desktop support (indicator problem) and received this "We are not currently developing a new version for Linux and do not have plans for doing so in the near future." So I believe developling Viber for Ubuntu Touch is also not their plan.  Is there any 3rd party application than can connect to Viber?

Comment: You'll have to ask Viber that as well, or see if they offer an API that allows third-party applications to connect to their services.