# Ubuntu Touch: Google Hangouts on bq M10

Tags: ubuntu-touch, browser, google-hangouts, m10

Google Hangouts doesn't work in the default browser on Ubuntu Touch OTA10.1. It just gives a message "It appears as if you're using an old or uncommon browser that doesn't support common standards".

I also tried it with Firefox, but it claims to need a plugin, which I can of course not install.

The Ubuntu Hangups app doesn't support calls (video or voice), so it doesn't help either.

Comment: Did you try it with Firefox, or the one just labeled "Browser"?

Comment: Yes, I tried both.

Comment: It turns out that this is a known issue, and supposedly fixed in the `rc-proposed` channel (meaning that the fix will be available in OTA-11 in a few weeks). See https://plus.google.com/+OliverGrawert/posts/aZi13q1bcWw and https://plus.google.com/u/0/+MikeKelly87/posts/32EUgtorgWJ

Comment: @Jens Grivolla How did you switch to rc-proposed? Because I have tried it using several tutorials but it either does not switch at all despite saying it downloaded the update from rc-proposed after switching or gives random errors in the desktop terminal...

Comment: I tried to follow http://askubuntu.com/a/764560/532550 but it didn't work. So I installed the necessary tools on my desktop (https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/phone/devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/) and ran `ubuntu-device-flash touch --channel=ubuntu-touch/rc/bq-aquaris-pd.en` from there (though it didn't succeed on the first attempt).  Do not go into recovery mode to do it, just run it when the tablet is powered up normally (but you need to enable developer mode).

Comment: I've added it as an answer here: http://askubuntu.com/a/770256/532550

Answer (score 5):

It turns out that this is a known issue, and supposedly fixed in the rc-proposed channel (meaning that the fix will be available in OTA-11 in a few weeks). See https://plus.google.com/+OliverGrawert/posts/aZi13q1bcWw and https://plus.google.com/u/0/+MikeKelly87/posts/32EUgtorgWJ

I have tried it using the default browser after switching the tablet to `rc-proposed` and can confirm that it does work (albeit with some problems selecting the camera): https://plus.google.com/+JensGrivolla/posts/JyrN4sJSqst