# How to change from Ubuntu touch stable channel to rc-proposed

Tags: ubuntu-touch

How to change from Ubuntu touch stable channel to rc-proposed without loosing any data on the device? Is that possible without backup and restoring the data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install the Terminal app from the store (or if you have enabled developer mode, you can use the `phablet-shell` tool over USB connection). If using Terminal app on the phone, you may need to disable screen locking *Battery Settings* first, as if the screen locks, the Terminal app (and its child processes) will be stopped. You can then change the setting back after switching channels.

Then, on the phone, run `sudo system-image-cli -vvvv --switch $newchannel` where `$newchannel` is the new channel you switch to switch to. For different devices, this channel may be different. For example, on the BQ Aquaris E4.5 and E5 Ubuntu Edition phones, the channel should be `ubuntu-touch/rc-proposed/bq-aquaris.en` to get rc-proposed. You can use `system-image-cli -i` to show current information, and generally just replace the `stable` portion of the existing channel name with `rc-proposed` to get the right channel. You can also perform the same action in reverse to switch back.

Comment: In my case it worked to set the device in developer mode and used phablet-shell to connect to the device. Making it directly in terminal app on the device did not work in my case.

Comment: Updated answer to mention lifecycle limitation of terminal app.

Comment: I'm getting a signature error when running `sudo system-image-cli -vvvv --switch ubuntu-touch/rc-proposed/bq-aquaris-pd.en` on my BQ M10. Any ideas?

Comment: I finally got it to work running `ubuntu-device-flash touch --channel=ubuntu-touch/rc/bq-aquaris-pd.en` from my desktop computer.

Comment: Only the previous comment from Jens works for me on E4.5.

Comment: adb devices is showing my device as "unauthorized" when trying to run the ubuntu-device-flash command on my LG Nexus 4. Developer mode is enabled. When it's disabled, adb devices doesn't even show my Nexus 4. Any ideas how to solve the unauthorized problem so I can change the channel?

Comment: Unlock the screen and authorize the device when you plug it in with adb enabled.

Comment: @dobey, thanks for the reply. The mobile device is already running Ubuntu Touch, so it doesn't get an Android authorize device prompt when I plug it in.

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible to follow the instructions here, it appears to only change the system partition: https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/phone/devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/

I think these are the important steps (on an Ubuntu desktop):

1. Add the Ubuntu SDK Release PPA:

   `$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa`
2. Update your system to use the latest packages:

   `$ sudo apt-get update`
3. Install the ubuntu-device-flash package

   `$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-device-flash`
4. switch the channel, e.g. for the bq M10:

   `ubuntu-device-flash touch --channel=ubuntu-touch/rc/bq-aquaris-pd.en`

Your tablet needs to be running, with developer mode enabled (and connected via USB to the desktop). You do not need to boot into recovery mode. If it doesn't work keep trying, it doesn't always work on the first attempt.