# Bq Aquaris M10: stuck on boot logo after switching channels

Tags: boot, ubuntu-touch, tablet, m10

I tried the steps from Jens (see his post in: [How to change from Ubuntu touch stable channel to rc-proposed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/764554/how-to-change-from-ubuntu-touch-stable-channel-to-rc-proposed/770256#770256)) and it says that it can't boot into recovery mode. Next, it does reboot to recovery mode and it only says "Installing Ubuntu update" on the tablet but the desktop has lost the connection. It failed and now it hangs on the Powered by Ubuntu screen, so it does not boot anymore. I can still reach Fastboot Mode and tried reflashing in that mode but it didn't help. What to do now? Please help asap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reflash with the image from bq support site http://www.mibqyyo.com/en-download/ using the flash tools for Linux they provide.

Similar to this process.
https://www.google.co.uk/url?q=http://www.ubuntugear.com/2015/02/flash-ubuntu-on-bq-aquaris.html%3Fm%3D1&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwjWgsONlu3MAhWQHsAKHTOIB_YQFggVMAM&usg=AFQjCNFGVFJuEGQTc06jw4ReNES9SPso7g