# How to make video calls with Skype on Ubuntu tablet m10 aquarius?

Tags: skype, m10

How would you make Skype video calls on Ubuntu tablet m10?
And how does it work?

Comment: If you are wanting to make Video calls - not specifically Skype - then it looks like you'll be able to use Google Hangouts when OTA-11 comes out. Here's a link that Jens Grivolla found (https://plus.google.com/+OliverGrawert/posts/aZi13q1bcWw) in answer to a question about Hangouts not working at the moment. The question is here: (http://askubuntu.com/questions/759832/ubuntu-touch-google-hangouts-on-bq-m10)

Answer (score 2):

Skype has not released a voice calling app for Ubuntu phones, or for the ARM architecture, so there is no way to perform video calls with Skype on that device at the moment.

I'd suggest asking Skype to provide an app for Ubuntu phones and tablets.

Comment: I just don't believe it!!!!????