# Ubuntu Touch - Webcam chat app

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I have a Ubuntu tablet and so does my son. We want to use an app like Skype to have chats when he is overseas. I downloaded Skype the other day hoping to be able to have these webcam chats. However, there does not seem to be any option to hold cam chats. There is no option either in Telegram. So is there any paps that I can install where we can hold cam chats between our two tablets?

Comment: You could try Google Hangout - which had issues on Ubuntu Touch (http://askubuntu.com/questions/759832/ubuntu-touch-google-hangouts-on-bq-m10) in the past - not sure how the current status is.

Comment: I have successfully used Google Hangout in the default browser on the bq M10. To get it to work you needed to run software from the rc-proposed channel, but with the OTA11 release becoming available today it should work for everybody.

Comment: I will have to have a look at this as the default browser didn't work for me and it said I needed a supported browse. I tried the firefox browser, but find that totally unusable.

Comment: I have since used hangouts via the web browser and it can be done. The camera and microphone work via the browser, but not via the web app. In the web app you are unable to turn the camera or microphone on. However, via the browser you are unable to activate the front camera on. So if anyone knows how to change cameras in the hangouts browser version please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I currently feel that there is a need for more than one option when wishing to make video calles with the Ubuntu Tablets. At present, I have only been able to get Google Hangouts to work, via the web version. The apps that are in the store, do not allow the microphone or camera to connect, they are blocked. Also on the web version, the front camera cannot be activated, just the rear. So instrad of the person you are talking to seeing your face, they can only see your feel. However, based on the fact that there is a way to make video calls on the tablets, I am closing this question and will maintain the following [Enable camera in Google Hangouts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/786832/ubuntu-touch-how-to-enable-camera-microphone-for-google-hangouts), to resolve the issues with Hangouts, as described above.