# Ubuntu Touch - How to enable camera & microphone for Google Hangouts

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I have downloaded Google Hangouts and it looks like I can hold video calls. However, when I try to have a video call, it says the camera and microphone are blocked. It says to allow then via the URL. There is no URL.

How can I unblock the camera and microphone to allow video calls to be made? I have had a look in settings > security & privercy, but there is nothing there. Any advice would be great.

Comment: It doesn't work via app (two apps you will find in the ubuntu store), but try instead to start your video call via the web browser app. It worked but I didn't manage to switch to the second camera ... if you find out, it would be nice to post.

Comment: @JUVo thanks for that. I tried it on the browser and now I am able to make a video call. I was unable to turn the camera around though, which is a shame as I could only see my feet lo. I will look into seeing if I can change the camera around. However this is a great start to make cam chats on the tablet..

Comment: The one app that I am using from the app store, is a webapp as it is taking me to the same screen as the browser version. It is a shame that we cannot allow the camera and microphone in the app to like you can in the browser.

Comment: I have raised this in Launchpad under https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/archipel-agent-iphone-notification/+bug/1598994 @JuVo, please feel free to add comments to the bug report and say that it is affecting you too.

Comment: Now after the latest OTA-12 update the front camera in the web version of Google Hangouts works and a face to face web chat can be made. However, the front camera is on the side view and it cannot be changes. So the person you are talking to needs to tilt their head to talk to you. The camera cannot even be turned around with the tablets rotational lock on. Bug has been updated.